# Access validation not working

Tags: ms-access

I want to only display the age between 5 and 12 in a textbox in MS access. The age field is not the table but rather calculated. Here is the code

=Int((Now()-[Date Of Birth])/365.25)

Now the validation is not working. Here is the code:

> =5 And <=12

When the age >12 the validation text does not shows up? How do I solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a proper function for calculating age - like this:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

Then validation should probably be:

```
>=5 And <=12
```

but validation only works for *input* which will not happen as the control is bound to an expression. And when you think about it, what action could be taken against and "invalid" output from an expression?

Answer (score 0):

**Fist**, in order to get relayable time interval between days, Use [DateDiff](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) function. Your age function should be like this: `Int(DateDiff("d",[Date Of Birth],Now()/365.25)`
**Second**, you want conditional display, the use [IIf](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) function. This should be your control sours:

```
=IIf(Int(DateDiff("d",[Date Of Birth],Now())/365.25)>=5 and Int(DateDiff("d",[Date Of Birth],Now())/365.25)<=12,Int(DateDiff("d",[Date Of Birth],Now())/365.25),Null)
```

As Gustav has pointed, validation text is not relevant in this case.